# How to paste formatted text in textbox

Tags: c#, email, textbox, format, paste

I have this app that sends bulk emails. I want the user to press a button that will paste the emails into a textbox which is quite easy.

Now, I want each email to have a semi-colon at the end and a space between it and another email. Anyone have an idea on how I can go about that.

Comment: Try to elaborate more. Right now it is not quite clear what are you trying to do and what problem you have faced. Some source code as well as sample data might be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like some pretty simply string appending if you ask me. But you'll need to elaborate on your question since I could be way off..

Comment: I tried posting a picture but stack won't allow me. Its like this,          I have a long list of emails in notepad which i want to paste into a textbox in my application with a button click which i can do. Am now trying to put a semi-colon(;) at the end of each email i.e {me@yahoo.com; oruns@gmail.com; me@yahoo.com}. I want each email to have a semi-colon at their back when the user clicks the paste button. How can i go about that.

Comment: Well, how are the mails separated now? are they real mails or just adresses as you have shown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the clipboard class to retrieve information [from](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the clipboard.

```
public String RetrieveClipboardHtmlText(String replacementHtmlText)
{
    String returnHtmlText = null;
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Html))
    {
        returnHtmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
    }
    return returnHtmlText;
}
```

As for the other issue, your emails are going to need some sort of delimiter. Otherwise it'd be impossible to tell where the top level domain ends for one email ( IE .com, .org, .biz) and the next email begins, so its just going to be pretty simple string manipulation.